# Clicking on "Answering my question" is allowed more that one time

Tags: bug, answers, user-interface

Yesterday, Stack Overflow was slow (or may be it came from our network) and I noticed that you can click more than one time on the "Answer Your Question" button which shouldn't be allowed.

[image: Taking a while to load...]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Do you mean that it took time to respond so you could click twice?

Comment: And what are the negative consequences of not prohibiting this behavior?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Exactly.

Comment: @Servy It's Just a small improvement indeed.

Comment: @COil So you're saying there are none?

Comment: So it doesn't change ANYTHING if you click twice?  do you give rep twice, is the answer somewhat invalidated by the double click?

Comment: @Servy: That would just prevent stupid users to report this kind of things. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes: Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange sites in general) load things in segments (i.e. not everything is loaded when you "load" the page).

Some things, like "Answer Your Question" (which will load a dialog asking you to confirm that you *really* want to answer your own question) and flagging (which will load a dialog asking you for details of what you want to flag), will take some extra time to load when you click on the button that activates them.

If your network connection is slow, it will take a while, so you may run into things like this:

[image: Flag dialog being slow]

Maybe multiple clicks shouldn't be allowed, but the actual prompt (or answer dialog) won't be loaded multiple times, so it's not really a problem.

Comment: It's not a real problem indeed but the fix seems easy.

Comment: Then you get a little "you cannot load the flag dialog 2,048 times" message :-)